# How to change True/False with string in column in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert True/False value in a particular column with some string value but it is not coming. How can i do? True/False are boolean.

Example:

df1:

```
col1  col2  col3
Ram   shyam True
axa   moh   False
sur   ami   True
```

Expected Output:

df:

```
col1  col2  col3
Ram   shyam right
axa   moh   False
sur   ami   right
```

Comment: Where ist the error and code that produced it? You are effectively casting `False` to be a string then, not a boolean anymore.

Comment: it is not giving error . It is not replacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

dct = {"col1": ["Ram", "axa", "sur"],
       "col2": ["shyam", "moh", "ami"],
       "col3": [True, False, True]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)

df1['col3'] = np.where(df1['col3'] == True, 'right', 'False')
print(df1)
```

This yields

```
  col1   col2   col3
0  Ram  shyam  right
1  axa    moh  False
2  sur    ami  right
```

Note that this changes the type of the column `col3` from `bool` to `object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple **[`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)** command like this:

```
In [1546]: df['col3'] = df['col3'].replace({True:'right'})
In [1547]: df
Out[1546]: 
  col1   col2   col3
0  Ram  shyam  right
1  axa    moh  False
2  sur    ami  right
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df["col3"] = df["col3"].apply(lambda x: "right" if x==True else False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to replace strings across multiple cols but not the whole dataframe, here's an example I didn't see in the docs

```
df[cols] = df[cols].replace({"old": "new"})
```